# How do you install samsung Kies to an alternative hard drive?

Tags: updates, installation, samsung-kies

I am trying to install Kies in order to get Ice cream sandwich for my galaxy note 1, my C drive is full and I would like to install on D drive which has plenty of space.

Comment: Kies should be able to be installed on any drive regardless of letter... so what's the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your version of Kies doesn't let you specify a path, use `mklink`.

```
Creates a symbolic link.

MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target

    /D      Creates a directory symbolic link.  Default is a file
            symbolic link.
    /H      Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
    /J      Creates a Directory Junction.
    Link    specifies the new symbolic link name.
    Target  specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link
            refers to.
```

So if the default install path was `C:\Program Files\Kies` and you want to install to `D:\Kies`, you would create the latter directory and then run `mklink /D /J "C:\Program Files\Kies" "D:\Kies"` before installing.